# Using prependTo for one element of a class loads all elements with same class

Tags: jquery

I'm having multiple div tags of the same class with radio choices which I converted to select options. Everything is fine until I try to prepend the "used to be" h4 now "option selected" to the select tag. I cannot figure out how to make prependTo move "each" particular selected option to it's corresponding select tag. I have tried, .next(), css sibling, .prependTo() immediately after converting it to option but I keep loading all of h4 tags that follow as well.

What would be the proper way to use prependTo here?

Thanks

Shown below is the original HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperAttribsOptions">
<h4 class="optionName back">Color</h4>
<div class="row">
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="16" id="attrib-1-16"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-16">Red ( +$0.10 )   (0.1lbs) </label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="25" id="attrib-1-25"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-25">Orange ( +$0.20 )   (+0.1lbs) </label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="17" id="attrib-1-17"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-17">Yellow ( +$0.30 )   (0.1lbs) </label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="26" checked="checked" id="attrib-1-26"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-26">Green</label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="15" id="attrib-1-15"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-15">Blue ( +$0.40 )</label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="27" id="attrib-1-27"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-27">Purple   (+0.1lbs) </label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="28" id="attrib-1-28"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-28">Brown</label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="30" id="attrib-1-30"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-30">White</label>
<input type="radio" name="id[1]" value="31" id="attrib-1-31"><label class="attribsRadioButton zero" for="attrib-1-31">Silver</label>

</div>
<hr>
</div>
```

I added the following:

```
$('.wrapperAttribsOptions input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<option class="ipad-option">' + $(this).next('label').text() + '</option>');
});
$('.ipad-option').next('label').remove();

$('.wrapperAttribsOptions .row').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<select class="ipad-select">' + $(this).html() + '</select>');
});

$('h4.optionName').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith('<option class="ipad-option-selected" selected>Select ' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
});
```

Getting the result shown below:

```
<div class="wrapperAttribsOptions">
<option class="ipad-option-selected" selected="">Select Color</option>
<select class="ipad-select">
<option class="ipad-option">Red ( +$0.10 )   (0.1lbs) </option>
<option class="ipad-option">Orange ( +$0.20 )   (+0.1lbs) </option>
<option class="ipad-option">Yellow ( +$0.30 )   (0.1lbs) </option>
<option class="ipad-option">Green</option>
<option class="ipad-option">Blue ( +$0.40 )</option>
<option class="ipad-option">Purple   (+0.1lbs) </option>
<option class="ipad-option">Brown</option>
<option class="ipad-option">White</option>
<option class="ipad-option">Silver</option>

</select>
<hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, got it.

I added this:

```
$('.ipad-option-selected').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).next('.ipad-select'));
});
```